# Unable to get NUnit to display in Create Unit Test dialog in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

Having read a few answers, such as this one [How to run NUnit tests in Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007761/how-to-run-nunit-tests-in-visual-studio-2017) I am still at a loss and cannot get Visual Studio to play well.

Here is what I have done, and what I am finding to not work well for me.

NUnit 3 Test Adapter Extension has been added

[image: NUnit 3 Test Adapter Extension has been added]

Added NUnit and NUnit.Console packages to my test project

[image]

I have no NUnit in the Create Unit Test Dialog

[image]

I did have an issue where live testing wasn't testing my tests too, though that was resolved by adding the Nuget package NUnit3TestAdapter to my project; this seems odd given i have added the extension?

[image]

Is there anything I can do to get other test frameworks to display in the create test dialog, and perhaps other areas of VS2017 that may be affected?

Answer (score 4):

Ah, Needed to install another extension called "Test Generator NUnit extension"

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem with Visual Studio 2022, for which this extension doesn't seem to be available. Any suggestions on what to do?