# Visual Studio 17: Facing Test Case not found issue in Visual Studio 17

Tags: winforms

I am currently working in Visual Studio Professional 2015, and moved to Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise for Code Coverage Testing (because code coverage is available only in Enterprise editions), the problem here is that the test cases which  were running fine in VS 2015, are not found by VS 2017. Can't figure out the issue.

Here is the Log:
No test is available in ProjectPath\bin\Debug\ProjectName.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

[image]

Comment: From the screen shot it seems you are using NUnit. Did you already see this SO post: [How to run NUnit tests in Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007761/how-to-run-nunit-tests-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Thanks bro, that helped, i was missing Nunit Adapter.