# Nunit 3 GUI runner

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm running Nunit tests using VS2017 Test Explorer and installed Nunit & Nunit3TestAdapter. 
Went to https://github.com/TestCentric/testcentric-experimental-gui/releases and tried both TestCentric Experimental GUI 0.7 & NUnit Gui 0.6 Preview versions and was not able to run my tests.

Did anyone try any of the above ? Was not able to find any guidance to what DLL needs to be upload etc. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run NUnit tests in Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007761/how-to-run-nunit-tests-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Well peeyush singh, the 2 are different questions. My question refers to the use of the new Nunit3 GUI runner (Currently under development) not how to configure VS to run Unit tests under Test Explorer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you are interested in the GUI. This has to be a very general answer, since you have not provided any indication of what code is not working.

The experimental GUI was... well, an experiment. It served it's purpose, which was to give a direction for development of the future GUI. The experiment has been terminated and the work continues elsewhere.

From the release notes of the 0.7 release:

"This is the final release of the TestCentric experimental GUI as a separate product. Future releases will be bundled with the standard TestCentric GUI once this project is merged into that repository."

Description of the Experimental GUI repository on GitHub:

"Experimental Gui test runner for NUnit 3 has been moved to the testcentric-gui project. Please file any issues there."

The TestCentric GUI project is located at http://github.com/TestCentric/testcentric-gui. It incorporates both the standard GUI, which looks like the old V2 NUnit GUI, and the experimental GUI that you were trying to use.

The project is now in it's fourth alpha release (1.0-alpha4) and a beta should be available fairly soon. You can file issues against either of the two GUIs - in fact it is best to see if any problems encountered arise in one of them or in the common code.

Bear in mind that the overall project is still alpha-level and I use "experimental" to mean something quite less than alpha. Some things will work and others may not. The standard GUI is more stable at this point. Also, check the existing issues for any that might apply to you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will have a look and see what I can get out of that.