# NUnit azuredevops pipeline

Tags: azure, testing, azure-devops, continuous-integration, nunit

I made some researches but still didn't figured out this problem.

So, I made an NUnit test project, selenium with c#.

Tried to add in AzureDevops pipeline.

here is the configuration in azure

[image]

I'm getting the following error -
[image]

I Tried to change those parameters. but didn't get any other result/error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipeline configuration is expecting the tests in the dll with the format `**\testhost.*test*.dll`. But your solution does not have any projects matching that convention.

Either you need to update the pipeline configuration to match the dll's in your project or have your tests in a different project. But you will still need to update the dll pattern as I am not sure what 'testhost' is in that?

Comment: what should I pass? I tried various combinations of parameters, neither works.

testhost is dll in debug, i tried RentEasly too.

Comment: try RentEasly.dll, assuming that is the dll name that you have when you build the project. You can check that in the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add the NUnit Test Adapter nuget to your project containing the tests.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43008337/736079

Answer (score 0):

When you run the test task initially it will fail. But when you see the error you can get the path of the dll files in working directory/in agent. Add that path in your task and re-run